# Smooth Scrolling disrupted by fixed header/footer

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling

I use the following script to smooth scroll across variable length articles.  The example below is focused on scrolling up to the top:

```
function scrollUp()
    {
        var duration = ($('#article').outerHeight(true) / 100) * 25 ;
        $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#article").offset().top
        }, duration);;
    }
```

How can I modify the above script to also say "actually smooth scroll an additional 100px higher than this?"

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add -100 to the script like so:

```
var duration = ($('#article').outerHeight(true) / 100) * 25 ;
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#article").offset().top - 100
}, duration);
```